# "ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied" for 'with recursive' statement on MariaDB 10.2.6

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.6. When a run a statement using root user, it works. However, if I try it with another user (with limited access) it fails saying that I don't have access to perform SELECT on the dynamically generated view. I can't explicitly grant SELECT to that table because it doesn't exists.

Here is the WITH RECURSIVE statement:

```
with recursive hierarchy (id, parent_department_id) as 
    (
        SELECT  id, parent_department_id
            from  department
            where  parent_company_id = 1
            union  all 
        select  e.id, e.parent_department_id
            from  department e
            join  hierarchy h  ON e.parent_department_id = h.id
    ) 
select  e.*
    from  hierarchy h
    join  department e  ON e.id = h.id;
```

The error:

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'aclapi'@'localhost' for table 'hierarchy'
```

When I log as root and try to grant SELECT on hierarchy to the user:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'vblpso.hierarchy' doesn't exist
```

How am I suppose to grant privileges to allow the WITH RECURSIVE statement to work (without using grant all priviges)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug (more likely), or at least a documentation deficiency. It has been filed now as https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13453 , you can track further progress there and comment if you have something to add.

For a workaround, you can grant `SELECT ON vblpso.*` to the user, assuming that `vblpso` is the default database when the user executes the query.

Comment: Thank you for creating and posting Jira bug report. I hope it is just a documentation issue.

Comment: Hmmm... Works for me in 10.2.2.  Also, it fails in other ways on 8.0.0.